# Idiom or proverb for "Productive members get punished for their hard work by getting dumped with more responsibilities

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

what is the idiom or proverb for

When good people/smart hard working people/productive employees are punished by pushing/dumping more responsibility on to them by the authority/management, etc because of their cognizant skills, alertness, diligence, sound judgement and/or overall productiveness while the lazy, delinquent, tardy, sloppy, unproductive receive less work or no work (for fear of bungling and still secure the post) for their same pay (as in a reward, bliss for wrong doing).

Comment: It's the horse which runs that gets whipped the most.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a phrase, idiom, or a proverb, the most clear and common recapitulation of your question is:

**

> "No good deed goes unpunished".

**

https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/No+good+deed+goes+unpunished.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_good_deed_goes_unpunished

Answer (score 1):

“The burden of competency”; the seemingly oxymoronic rationale that the more capable you are, the harder your work becomes. From competence follows increases in responsibility and workload.

Comment: In reality, increases in responsibility are likely followed with increases in compensation. Everyone always has the option of working below their potential, and can turn down opportunities for more work.

Comment: Unlikely where favoritism is abundant..